# Trying to get the value of name data inside an object (using Kendo Ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

so i have this simple object

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       data : ["One", "Two"]
    });
    console.log(dataSource.data[0]);

    kendo.bind($("#container3"), {});
```

im trying to get the value of "One" or "Two" but i always get undefined.

```
console.log(dataSource.data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
dataSource.transport.data[0]
```

instead of

```
 dataSource.data[0]
```

Comment: thank you where did you find this documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [data](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data) method to get the dataItems of the dataSource. Keep in mind the method will return an empty array if the dataSource is not populated with items via a call of either the fetch, read or query methods:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data : ["One", "Two"]
  });

  dataSource.fetch(function(){
    console.log(dataSource.data()[0]);
  })
```